# copy the data from xml file and paste in same file and overwrite using FIle.Copy()

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to copy data of one file and pasting it into the same file which means overwriting it. I learn that overwrite the file data using file.copy() cannot be possible. but from the one of the post says that if I use File.Copy(Source file, destination file, true) than overwrite is possible. I tried to use but it didn't work. if anyone have solution for that than it will be big help.

```
     public void EditRole(string oldRole, string newRole)
        {
          if (File.Exists(roleXMLLoc))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(roleXMLLoc);
                var edit = doc.Element("Roles").Elements("Role").Where(x => x.Value == oldRole).SingleOrDefault();
                edit.Value = newRole;
                doc.Save(roleXMLLoc);

                if (File.Exists(userPermissionLoc))
                {
                  File.Copy(userPermissionLoc, userPermissionLoc, true); SaveData();
                }
          }
}
```

Comment: You cannot overwrite a file that is open.  Best way is to write a temporary file, delete original file, and then rename temporary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read or write files you should open a Stream (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/). If you need to read and write in the same time, then you should use 2 separate streams for reading and writing into 2 separate files. Operating system will protect file from being opened by 2nd stream, otherwise you would fall into problems of concurrency: you read the inactual data that is already being changed by writing stream.
The logic can be:

1. Read file and close Reading stream. Then open file for writing and do what you need.
   OR
2. Open Reading stream for fileToRead.xml and open Writing stream for temporary fileToWrite.xml. After you done, you can close both streams, remove the source file and rename the new file.

Comment: Yeah I tried this too it doesn't work. but is there any other command which work exactly like File.Copy().